# How can I set "--webkit-backdrop-filter" with java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is how I did:
in css:

```
.titlebar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(12, 40, 82,0.9);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: var(effect);
    backdrop-filter: var(effect);
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

in js:

```
navBarBg.style.setProperty("effect","blur(20px)");
```

But it did not work! I also tried

```
    navBarBg.setAttribute("-webkit-backdrop-filter", "blur(0px)");
    navBarBg.setAttribute("backdrop-filter", "blur(0px)");
```

But they did not work either.

Comment: CSS variable names start with `--`, so you have to write `--effect` instead of `effect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as a property on the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) attribute. Note that modern versions of Chrome no longer show the `-webkit-` version of CSS properties.

```js
navBarBg.style['-webkit-backdrop-filter'] = 'blur(20px)';
navBarBg.style['backdrop-filter'] = 'blur(20px)';
```

```html
<div id="navBarBg">Inspect this element to see the style has been set</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the javascript notation webkitBackdropFilter? Or are both valid?

Comment: @somethinghere That's if you want to use "dot notation" for object properties like so: `navBarBg.style.webkitBackdropFilter`

Comment: Regardless of notation, though, the key apparently supports css and js type syntax? I did not know that.

Comment: @somethinghere Indeed they can, but you can't set many of the properties using the CSS syntax with dot notation because a dash character `-` cannot be used in variable/key names, e.g. `navBarBg.style.backdrop-filter` is invalid (syntax error). So if you'd like to have the properties appear as they would in a stylesheet, you must use the key string notation.

Comment: Got it! it really helps and solve my problem.